# Another view recycle issue custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I've done plenty of research and me and a college have spent hours trying to figure this one out. At the risk of this getting closed as a duplicate I had no where else to turn! I've come across a lot of solutions for the repeated ListView and I understand how Views are reused (with convertView) etc. However I can't seem to find where my issue is coming from. The problem has the same typical symptoms, if I enter text in one EditText in the list then 5-6 items down...the same text is there!

I've attached my `getView(...)` code below to help you guys help me but if you need anything else just let me know.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // inflator for all the views
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // the object where I will be getting my display data
    final Object currentItem = drawItems.get(position);

    // standard adapter/view stuff
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ROW:
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_textview, null);

            // get my views
            holder.editText= (EditText) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.line_edittextview);


            break;

        case TYPE_SUMMARY:

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_summary, null);

            break;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Convert View Tag being set: " + holder);
        v.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,
                "Getting holder from Convert View Tag: " + v.getTag());
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    switch (type) {

    case TYPE_ROW:

        Log.i(TAG, "Holder in use: " + holder);

        holder.editText.setText("Line " + (position + 1));

        break;

    case TYPE_SUMMARY:

        break;

    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return TYPE_BETSLIP;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Remove  if (v == null) and try

Comment: @ArmaanStranger removing that works in a sense... It means the view is redrawn every time no matter. This is obviously bad for performance plus if the user enters something in the text box and scroll the data is lost.

Comment: what if type is TYPE_SUMMARY ?

Comment: @blackbelt Nothing at the minute, I return TYPE_ROW every time for testing. I'll update the question.

Comment: yeah right. if you don't want to make performance issue then you should give textview proper unique tag. and on textchange listener you  can save that data to Shared Preferences with key as tag of textview. and in getview method set text to textview if the tag has value in SP. and if don't then don't forget to give else statement where set text ="" so that textview don't display anything.

Comment: @Peter try setting a fix text for the TYPE_SUMMARY and check if this fix your issue

Comment: @blackbelt That didn't work :(

Comment: what does "not work" mean

Comment: @blackbelt The data wasn't repeated but the EditView entry was still saving data.

Answer (score 0):

I would say handle the views in every flow that is possible. That is, if you do something in your **if** undo it in **else**. Similarly, In your code, undo the setting of text that you have done like

```
case TYPE_ROW:
    holder.textView.setText("Line " + (position + 1));
    break; 
case TYPE_SUMMARY:
    holder.textView.setText("");
    break;
```

Hope this works.
Secondly, you are inflating 2 views for a list. I would recommend you to use one with the Visibility of the other set to `GONE` or so.

Comment: A good idea and I will implement this but since I'm returning only one type for testing, this shouldn't matter should it? Since the TYPE_SUMMARY case will never be hit...